# Probability question with black and white marbles

Tags: probability

Just looking for some help with this question. The answer seems obvious but I am questioning myself as it seems a little too obvious.

Max has a bag containing 2 black marbles and 2 white marbles. He draws a marble and sets it aside without looking at it. He then draws a second marble from the bag and it is white. Which is more likely?

A) The first marble drawn was equally likely to be black or white.
B) The first marble drawn was black.
C) The first marble drawn was white.

At first glance it would seem that A is the correct answer as the first draw is an independent event. But does knowing the result of the second draw affect the number of outcomes for the first draw?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Well, what answer do you consider to be obviously correct?

Comment: I edited the question to include what I thought 

Comment: Ah, that's wrong.  It's not independent because you have extra information (namely that the second draw is white).  Just to stress:  suppose the urn starts with $1$ black and $1$ white, and you know the second draw is white.  Then you are absolutely certain that the first one was black.

Comment: I like the urn analogy! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Bayes' Theorem is one way to do this, but it isn't necessary.

Suppose the balls were labeled $W_1,W_2,B_1,B_2$ and that the second draw was $W_1$.  Then we know the first ball must have been one of $W_2,B_1,B_2$.  Nothing distinguishes these except for color so any one of them is equally likely to have been the first one chosen.  Thus the probability that the first draw was Black is $\frac 23$ and the probability that it was White is $\frac 13$.

To help with intuition, here is another way to look at it.  Imagine we draw out all $4$ balls (though in the end we only care about the first two draws).  There are $\binom 42=6$ equally probable ways the balls might be ordered.  We have $$WWBB,WBWB,WBBW,BBWW,BWBW,BWWB$$  Of these, only three have $W$ as the second draw, namely:  $$WWBB,BWBW,BWWB$$
Thus, we know we are in one of these three states, each with probability $\frac 13$.  We remark that in two of these three cases, the first ball is $B$.

To stress:  I am assuming here that the first draw is NOT returned to the bag.  It is drawn and then hidden away somewhere, not in the bag.  That is critical.  If, to the contrary, you show it to a friend (who notes the color) and then return it to the bag, then the two draws are entirely independent.  In the context of my solution above, if you have replaced the first draw in the bag then there was no reason to exclude $W_1$ from the list of possibilities.

Comment: That was what I was torn between! I mapped out the possibilties knowing the second marble was white so the outcomes could be: black/white, black/white or white/white. So I got the same answer 2/3 chance of the first being black and 1/3 chance of it being white. However, I consulted with a few math teachers and they all told me that it doesn't matter what the second draw was because the first draw is independent of it.

Comment: @Halifaxgirl  Well, they would be correct if you put the first draw back in the bag.  I should stress that:  I was assuming that you took the first draw and hit it away somewhere...i.e. not back in the bag.  That is critical.

Comment: @Halifaxgirl  One of the many great things about discrete probability is that you can just check by experiment.  Using a computer or even with a bag containing $4$ marbles, just try it out and see what you get in practice.

Comment: Yes the first marble is set aside and not put back in the bag. I feel like this is a difficult question for an intro to math course!

Comment: So I took the quiz and the prof says the answer was A - equal chance of black and white. Is there anything I can say to defend my answer of B?

Comment: Well, if we are clear on the rules I don't understand the answer $A$ at all.  If you were playing poker it would be like saying that "even though I was dealt four aces, my opponent might also have four aces because her hand is independent from mine."  Nonsense.  So..show the answer I wrote (at some point I added another argument to it).  Then, I'd propose a computer simulation.  Try it $100,000$ times and see how it comes out.

Comment: To do the simulation:  number the balls $1,2,3,4$. Say $1,2$ are white and $3,4$ are black (or whatever).  For each trial draw a number at random from this list, then draw a second from the remaining three.  Discard the trial if the second draw is black, otherwise keep it.  Record the color of the first draw and repeat.  You can do this with a real bag containing marbles as well, but with the computer you can do a lot more trials.

Comment: Thank you! I think the prof will say that it doesn't matter that he drew a white marble second, but clearly it does. One cannot simply choose to ignore that information. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If it seems obviously correct, then it probably is. To be sure of yourself, you can use Bayes Theorem: $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

We have

$$P(\text{first is white}|\text{second is white})=\frac{P(\text{first is white}\cap\text{second is white})}{P(\text{second is white)}}$$

If this value is less than $0.5$ we would conclude that black is more likely.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am completely new to this and it is for an online course so the instruction has been a bit lacking. No formulas have been taught or provided so I'm not exactly sure how to figure it out. I think that it is A as there is an equal chance on the first draw, but does knowing the outcome of the second draw affect the possibilities of what marbles were drawn first?

Comment: Do you know what the symbols in my answer mean?

Comment: Not all of them. Sorry!!!! The course is just supposed to be an overview of math in general so we don't go into symbols and formulas unfortunately. Which is why I suppose the prof wouldn't expect us to use a particular formula to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the second marble is white means the first draw had to be between one white marble and one black marble, if it is done WITHOUT REPLACEMENT: that is, when the second draw is known, that selection is already spoken for, and the universe of possibilities for the first draw is CUT DOWN.  So the p(white first) = p(black first) = 1/2, as the second draw has already been decided.

This can be shown using Bayes Theorem:

Let A = white 1st;

Let B = white 2nd:

p(A|B) = p(B|A)*p(A)/p(B), where p(A) is the prior probability before any data is observed, p(B) is the marginal probability.

In terms of A, B above:

p(white 1st | white 2nd) = p(white 2nd | white 1st)*p(white 1st before data) / [p(w1  | w2)p(w2) + p(w2 | black 1st)p(b1)]

p(white 1st) = p(w1) = 2/3 before any data is observed.

p(black 1st) = p(b1) = 1/3 before any data is observed

p(w2|w1) = prob that white is picked 2nd after white 1st = 1 white/(b+w left) = 1/2

p(w2|b1) = prob that white is picked 2nd after black 1st = 1 white/(w+w left) = 1

Hence, p(w1|w2) = p(w2|w1)p(w1)/[p(w2|w1)p(w1)+p(w2|b1)p(b1)]
= (1/2)(2/3)/[(1/2)(2/3)+(1)(1/3)] = (1/3)/[1/3+1/3)] = (1/3)/(2/3) = 1/2.

Hence, p(b1|w2) = p(w2|b1)p(b1)/[p(w2|b1)p(b1)+p(w2|w1)p(w1)]
= (1)(1/3)/[(1)(1/3)+(1/2)(2/3)] = (1/3)/[1/3+1/3)] = (1/3)/(2/3) = 1/2.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: two black marbles...

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that one white marble was *destined* to be the second marble drawn, entails that there were **three** marbles in the bag which were *equally likely* to have been the first marble drawn (*and set aside*), and only **one** among them was white .

It is the same senario as drawing a white marble and asking what the probability that the next marble will be white ... just with the video played backwards.